# Assign second element in a pair to a vector

Tags: python, numpy, vector, assign

Am I making some simple mistake or is this a bug? Trying to assign the first and second element of a pair to separate vectors in Python Numpy, but the second element gets assigned to both vectors in all cases. 
Desired output: `sol[0]` identical to `pxvec[i]`.

```
srange = np.linspace(0, 0.7, 10)
pxvec = srange 
pyvec = srange 
pindex = 0

for i in srange: 
    sol=[i,i+1]
    print(sol[0],sol[1])
    pxvec[pindex]=sol[0]
    pyvec[pindex]=sol[1]
    print(pxvec[pindex],pyvec[pindex])
    pindex=pindex+1
```

Output I am getting:

```
0.0 1.0
1.0 1.0
0.07777777777777778 1.0777777777777777
1.0777777777777777 1.0777777777777777
0.15555555555555556 1.1555555555555554
1.1555555555555554 1.1555555555555554
0.23333333333333334 1.2333333333333334
1.2333333333333334 1.2333333333333334
0.3111111111111111 1.3111111111111111
1.3111111111111111 1.3111111111111111
0.3888888888888889 1.3888888888888888
1.3888888888888888 1.3888888888888888
0.4666666666666667 1.4666666666666668
1.4666666666666668 1.4666666666666668
0.5444444444444445 1.5444444444444445
1.5444444444444445 1.5444444444444445
0.6222222222222222 1.6222222222222222
1.6222222222222222 1.6222222222222222
0.7 1.7
1.7 1.7
```

​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign `pxvec`and `pyvec` to copies of `srange`, otherwise every change you will make to `pxvec`will also be made to `pyvec`and `srange`(it's called copy by reference if you want to look this up)

```
srange = np.linspace(0, 0.7, 10)
pxvec = srange.copy()
pyvec = srange.copy()
```

And then you can continue with the code you have provided